# Error bars drift away from the main bars

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to draw bar graphs with error bars. Here is my script,

```
set term pngcairo
# ... some setup code

set style data histogram
set style fill solid 1.00 border
set style histogram gap 1 errorbars lw 1
set ytics 800
set output "thttpd.png"

plot 'thttpd.dat' using 2:3:xtic(1) title col(2)
```

My data is like this,

```
File_size Original_thttpd    std_dev      priv    std_dev

16 617.525151042  46.4794798061  623.229175781  17.4696494741
32 1094.72792871  36.709731068  1105.89255892  21.3383446583
64 1736.16701074  14.9846134633  1738.41502295  23.9069441408
......
```

I got figure,

[image]

As you can see, the error bars are separated from the main bar. I'm using `gnuplot 5.2`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bug that was fixed sometime between version 5.2.2 and 5.2.4.
The program failed to recognize that use of "title col(2)" in your plot command necessarily implies the presence of an extra row of data containing column headings.  You can bypass this failure by adding the command

```
set key autotitle columnhead
```

That will ensure that the program knows about the row of column header labels
even if the autotitle feature isn't used for a particular plot.